How to create complicated plots in matplotlibcpp?
This is Python code for a logarithmic Matplotlib figure:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

n = [i for i in range(1, 30)]
a = n;
b = [1/i for i in range(1, 30)]
c = [math.sqrt(i) for i in range(1, 30)]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(n, a, label="Data A", marker='o')
plt.plot(n, b, label="Data B", marker='s')
plt.plot(n, c, label="Data C", marker='^')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel('Data')
plt.title('My data.')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


How would I create something like this in c++?
I'm currently using the matplotlibcpp.h library.
But I'm starting to think that this library is not capable of producing plots like shown above.
Here's one of my attempts:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>      // For std::sqrt
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main() {
    // Generate data
    std::vector<int> n;
    std::vector<double> a;
    std::vector<double> b;
    std::vector<double> c;

    for (int i = 1; i < 30; ++i) {
        n.push_back(i);
        a.push_back(i);                  // Data A
        b.push_back(1.0 / i);            // Data B (1/i)
        c.push_back(std::sqrt(i));       // Data C (sqrt(i))
    }

    // Create a figure
    plt::figure_size(1000, 600);
    plt::semilogy(n, a);
    plt::semilogy(n, b);
    plt::semilogy(n, c);
    plt::xlabel("N");
    plt::ylabel("Data");
    plt::title("My data.");
    plt::legend();
    plt::grid(true);
    plt::show();

    return 0;
}



It's pretty close but I'm still struggling to add (both) legend and markers.
Which isn't as easy as it seems, since the plot functions don't take any additional parameters.
Thanks for any help!

Given that that library has 189 open issues and 32 pull requests with a last commit date of "3 years ago", looks like it's up to you to fix your own bug.

That said, I think you should use the legend(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& keywords) overload instead of legend().

@Botje I did try:
map<string, string> l1;
l1["label1"] = "Data A";
l1["label2"] = "Data B";
l1["label3"] = "Data C";
plt::legend(l1); But it crashed the program.

Looking at the code, that overload is just for passing the kwargs of legend(). Sorry. You will have to read the source...

At least for me, MatPlot++ has worked out better. https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus The general style is similar, but it's been updated more recently, and (at least for what I've tried to do) has worked better. And yes, that has included line graphs with both legends and markers.
